# How can I force the postinst for package A to run before the one for package B without depending on it?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, apt, package-management, packaging

(Hint to the reader: For the purpose of this post you can safely ignore what ufw is and how it actually works. My question is not about ufw, but about packaging).

I have my own Deb package *mypackage*. It does some networking and requires certain ports to be open. It is safe to assume that the only firewall that might be in place is *ufw*. I want my package to not depend on ufw's presence. Instead, I want its `postinst` routine to determine whether or not `ufw` is in place, and if yes to add a rule. Here it my current `postinst`:

```
if ufw version > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    ufw allow in proto udp from any to any port 12345
fi
```

This works fine if ufw is installed, and it works fine if ufw is not installed.

It **fails** however if my package and ufw get installed at the same time:

```
apt-get install mypackage ufw
```

What happens is that mypackage and ufw get both unpackaged, then the `Setting up` phase is called first for mypackage, which finds ufw present (`ufw version` succeeds), but because it hasn't been setup yet, it doesn't work properly yet, and adding a rule fails:

```
Selecting previously unselected package mypackage.
Unpacking mypackage (from .../mypackage_1.0_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package ufw.
Unpacking ufw (from .../archives/ufw_0.31.1-2_all.deb) ...
# ...
Setting up mypackage (1.0) ...
ERROR: Couldn't stat '/etc/default/ufw'
ERROR: Couldn't stat '/etc/default/ufw'
dpkg: error processing mypackage (--configure):
  subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
```

How can I force the `--configure` for ufw to run before mine, without depending on ufw?